# Recommended library for building soap webservice client in Java

Tags: java, soap

I'm trying to access a soap webservice from a jsp page. I need something simple and lightweight as this is a mockup.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd like to offer the opinion that "SOAP" and "simple and lightweight" don't really go together.  =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have Java 6 or newer, you could use the built-in JAX-WS implementation.  Sun has a [guide](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/) on how to use it to build services.  It appears that the client implementation is in [Part 2](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2_pt2/).

Although they show how to generate the webservices client using the NetBeans IDE, you can also use the [wsimport](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) command-line client to do it, which is in the Java bin folder.

I believe the Eclipse [SoapUI plugin](http://www.soapui.org/IDE-Plugins/eclipse-plugin.html) can also generate JAX-WS web service artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

While Java6 has a built-in webservice implementation, it is, in my opinion, overly complex and hard to use.  My preference would be for [Spring-WS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/), which is leightweight and easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) and its ability to code generation could be the easier way in Java. Were you to use Groovy and GSP, you could use [GroovyWS](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS), which relies upon CXF under the hood, and allows litteraly no-brainer call to web-services (which is by the way possible in most of the cases thanks to support for [scripting languages of JVM](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/)).

Answer (score 1):

u can use spring's functionality. look at the section "17.5.2. Accessing web services using JAX-RPC" @ http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/remoting.html.

Or if you are not using spring, then generate stubs using the tooling provided by ur Java EE SDK to invoke the service

Answer (score 0):

I would use [JAX-WS](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/).

Answer (score 0):

For web-service, I suggest [Apache's Axis2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/) Engine. It's opnesource, you've the source so that you can learn more....

Comment: @skaffman: +1 though it is perhaps not quite as bad as Axis1. Axis1 still scares me with just how awful it was.